# Looking for a small (portable) web markdown log

Tags: markdown

I'm looking for something personal a small web log tool - it can be a C# Git project as well - to keep a Markdown based log.

**I love** Markdown.

I normally log the things I do or need to remember, inside a file.   Currently I use Notepad++, however I'm thinking it might be handy for others if they could see my logbook as well.

What's an easy way to get it locally made public?

(I'm thinking of showing my notes as local hosted Markdown page shown as web page on my laptop.)

Answer (score 1):

[Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) is a markdown-based note taking app that should suit.

Available for most platforms, it enables taking, editing and publishing notes in markdown format.  Notes are stored locally, folders and cross-links between notes are supported.

By default it will store notes in a local file structure.  However, it will link to external synchronisation sites such as github.

It is free for personal use.  However, if you wish to use the [Obsidian cloud sync](https://obsidian.md/sync) service, that is chargeable.

The [help pages](https://help.obsidian.md/Index) are themselves in Obsidian markup and show how you could make your notes public.